# Avoid showing login page when session is expired in ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session

I have a web application developed in codeigniter framework.

My issue is , i have lot of ajax calls in my backend, now on ajax call if session is expired, its showing login page in place where I wanted to load dynamic data.

How can I solve this issue without changing in all my ajax calls?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?= base_url("controller/method") ?>",
    data: {key1: value1,key2: value2},
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "HTML"
    success: function(){
        // here i'm processing the response.
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post Ajax code ?

Comment: If session expired you should get a Login page that is normal in web applications. Now what do you mean by 'dynamic data'?

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix i have added my ajax code.

Comment: @KOUSIKMANDAL, what you are telling is correct. Consider i have to load address for customer and show in view using ajax, and if session if session is expired, im seeing login form in place of address section.

Comment: Presumably you have code to redirect to the login page if the requested page is restricted and the user is not signed in. You can add a check to ensure that the request should not be an AJAX request as well before redirecting.

Comment: can you debug the Ajax request in developer console? it should be passing cookies, session headers along with it.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix, ya. That part is working fine. But if session is expired,it will load login page. But i want to redirect.

Comment: @apokryfos, that's good idea. Now we can only restrict loading of login page in view. But how can we redirect to login page??

Comment: @user7573053 what do you mean? On the AJAX request? Send back a 403 error code and add an `error` function in your ajax that does a `window.location.href = '/loginpageurl'` or something like that.

Comment: you have to do an client side redirect, `window.location.href=<URL>` assuming the response is just an redirect check the status code to ensure that you have to redirect the user .

Comment: @apokryfos, but I have to change this in all my ajax calls(I have more than 500 ajax calls through out my backend).

Comment: Could probably register a global [ajax error handler](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there is a easy solution for this,

In server side;

```
if($_SESSION['loggedin']=='false')   //assuming the login check
    header('app-stat : loggedout')   //send custom header to client
```

Now in the client side you check the header in ajax call.

The success function is like;

```
 success: function(data, textStatus, request){
    if(request.getResponseHeader('app-stat')=='loggedout')
    {
             //do what ever you want
    }
    else{
            //enjoy
    }
 },
```

Ok, and for your already added 500 ajax solution is;

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    //I think now you know what to do
});
```

Comment: This solution is fine, but I have to change this in all my ajax calls(I have more than 500 ajax calls through out my backend).

Comment: Added a solution please check.

Comment: I don't like these successful errors. That's that HTTP error codes are for.

Comment: @apokryfos absolutely right. But when you are developing new system you can code as you want. But in an existing system you sometimes have to break the 'textbook rules' :p .

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
class Controller_name extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id'); // Session id of user
        if(!$user_id || $user_id == '') 
        {
            if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') 
            { // Checking if ajax request received or not

                echo json_encode(array('status' => FALSE,'msg' => 'You are not logged in'));
                die;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And in your ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?= base_url("controller/method") ?>",
    data: {key1: value1,key2: value2},
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json"
    success: function(resp){
       if(resp.status == false)
       {
        alert(resp.msg);
       }
    }
});
```

**Note :** Here I'm using **dataType:'json** in ajax request